# Resizing the array, code from a book in C

Tags: c

I am currently trying to understand pointers from this book,
http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920028000.do

In chapter **Pointers and arrays**, under this heading **Using the realloc Function to Resize an Array** **page 87** author has given a snippet for how to resize array, if we don't know how many characters are going to be entered.

```
    /*read in characters
    from standard input and assign them to a buffer. The buffer will contain all of the
    characters read in except for a terminating return character
    */
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>

    char* getLine(void) 
    {
        const size_t sizeIncrement = 10;
        char* buffer = malloc(sizeIncrement);
        char* currentPosition = buffer;
        size_t maximumLength = sizeIncrement;
        size_t length = 0;
        int character;

        if(currentPosition == NULL) 
            { 
                return NULL; 
            }

        while(1) 
            {
                character = fgetc(stdin);
                if(character == '\n') 
                    { 
                        break; 
                    }

                if(++length >= maximumLength) 
                    {
                        char *newBuffer = realloc(buffer, maximumLength += sizeIncrement);
                        if(newBuffer == NULL) 
                            {
                                free(buffer);
                                return NULL;
                            }
                        currentPosition = newBuffer + (currentPosition - buffer);//what is the purpose of this??
                        buffer = newBuffer;
                    } 
                *currentPosition++ = character;
        }//while

        *currentPosition = '\0';
        return buffer;
    }

    int main(void)
    {
        char *s = getLine();
        printf("%s\n", s);
        return 0;
    }
```

I commented this part of the code

```
currentPosition = newBuffer + (currentPosition - buffer);
```

and ran the code. It still worked.
I am not sure, what purpose that line of code is for, becuase the evaluation for newBuffer and buffer will always cancel each other.

Is something missing from my understanding?

If not should I follow this book religiously?

Comment: It is because the reallocated memory might not be simply extended, but the whole thing reallocated in a different part of memory. So the position pointers must be updated.

Comment: but newBuffer will always point to same place, I mean to the location where buffer was. Isn't it? I printed the values of newBuffer and buffer and they are always the same.

Comment: Suppose you have other uses for allocated memory: you `malloc` some memory for your example, and    `malloc` some more for another purpose in the program - which happens to be contiguous with the first allocation. Can you see there is a problem reallocating the first memory block? The purpose of the pointer arithmetic here, is to ensure that `currentPosition ` points to the correct place.

Comment: Ohh. yes in that case it can't point to same place. Must try myself.

Comment: Aside `const size_t sizeIncrement = 10;` is mean - you could easily go for `100` or `1000` on a modern machine which would put less stress on the reallocation system.

Comment: The pointer arithmetic using pointers that are no longer guaranteed valid, much less part of the same sequence (they were, but are they *now*?), is questionable in itself. That is easily rectified, and makes the code easier to read in the process.

Comment: @WeatherVane yes you are right. I tried and it does not work without having this condition. newbuffer and buffer are not same too.Same is explained in the book but not that easy to have foresight what exactly is the case he is talking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`currentPosition = newBuffer + (currentPosition - buffer);`

so `(currentPosition - buffer)` is the offset (position - starting = offset)

after a realloc, the old pointer may or may not be good, it is UB... so you always need to use the new returned pointer... but the contents are copied. so it is like a new bigger buffer and you need to update your current position to the same offset in the new buffer ... so

`currentPosition = newBuffer + (currentPosition - buffer);`

makes perfect sense...